# Ready event that takes place after dom has loaded but before the user can see the dom

Tags: jquery

The problem I run into with using the window or document ready function is that, in some browsers, the user can see the DOM manipulation taking place while the page is loading. For example, If I were to remove an element inside window ready, the user can see the image load first, then be removed.

I understand that I can probably hide everything in CSS and then show it after my code is executed, but that's not really the solution I'm looking for. And it doesn't always work. For one, because JS is asynchronous, there's no way to know that your show function is going to fire after all other dom manipulations have finished.

Essentially what I want is a function which works just like document/window ready EXCEPT it takes place before the DOM is visible. After the dom is loaded but before it is visible - that's when I want to perform my manipulations.

Answer (score 5):

There are no events that satisfies what you're looking for. [See section 18.2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3).

This is called a [Flash of Unstyled Content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). A google search will show you more techniques. You're right though. The most common method with jQuery is to simply add `style="display: none"` to your body tag. Then later, at the end of your `ready` event call `$(body).show()`.

[@SarahBourt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304810/ready-event-that-takes-place-after-dom-has-loaded-but-before-the-user-can-see-th/26304921?#comment41278274_26304921) in the comments makes a good point about height calculations. If you can support modern browsers, and you need to maintain heights for some reason, then you may want to use `style="opacity: 0"` and `style="opacity: 1"` instead of `display` to hide/show your content.

If you need to make absolutely sure that all manipulation is done first. Then you will need to manually track all manipulations and trigger the `show` only when you're sure they're all completed.

Comment: If you're just worried about stylesheet loading, you can also just use a local "opacity: 0" on the container element and then a "opacity: 1 !important" on the stylesheet to be loaded.  This does not work on browsers older than IE9, but it provides a JavaScript free solution in some cases without messing up height calculations.

Answer (score 1):

> "After the dom is loaded but before it is visible - that's when I want
>   to perform my manipulations."

That's not possible, because that time doesn't exist.

The browser starts showing the DOM before it is completely loaded, so there is no time when the DOM is loaded and it's not visible yet.

The closest that you can get is to put a script tag right after the element that you want to work with, but even then the user might see the element for a little while.

Elements can become visible right after they have been parsed, and there is no event that you can use to get inbetween the parsing of the element and the element becoming visible. The only way to make the element reliably invisible while the page is loading is to use CSS to make it invisible before it even exists.